# Tips for accessing properties of child class in base class

Tags: c#, mef

I am creating classes for generating queries for various tables. each table have its own class . A class for the table called MetaTable looks like this

```
public  class MetaTableQueryCreator
{
    public  int userID { get; set; }
    public  int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public  string Tags { get; set; }
    public string FilePath_Pk {get;set;}


     public  MetaTableQueryCreator()
     {
         userID = 0;
         CategoryID = -1;
         Tags = string.Empty;

     }


    public   string GetInsertQuery()
    {
        string query = string.Empty;

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath_Pk))
        {
            // query = @"INSERT INTO MetaTable VALUES('" + userId + "', 1,'','','','','','','" + input + "','','','')";
        }
        else
        {

        }


        return query;
    }

    public  string GetDeleteQuery()
    {
        string query = string.Empty;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath_Pk))
        {
            // query = @"INSERT INTO MetaTable VALUES('" + userId + "', 1,'','','','','','','" + input + "','','','')";
        }


        return query;
    }

    public  string GetUpdateQuery()
    {
        string query = string.Empty;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath_Pk))
        {
            //query = @"INSERT INTO MetaTable VALUES('" + userId + "', 1,'','','','','','','" + input + "','','','')";
        }


        return query;
    }


}
```

I am using MEF in my application, so i need to create a base class for all these Query generator classes. I need to solve the following problem while creating the base class

1) I am having properties corresponding the fields in the table in each class. For each class it will have  a separate set of properties(corresponding the fields), so that i cannot put all these properties in the base class, since i am using the MEF i only have access to the properties defined in the base class in my main program. How can i solve this problem? Is there any better architecture for this problem?

Comment: Aside from anything else, please *don't* put the values for your parameters directly into your SQL. Use parameterized SQL instead.

Comment: You will have access to only the base class properties & methods only if you cast your objects to the base class. If the object is of the extended type then you will be able to access everything. What exactly are you asking - how to treat everything generically as the base class but still get to the extended members?

Comment: I would probalby split your class into QueryCreator and Table. And use it like QueryCreator.GetInsertQuery(Table)

Comment: @slugster I am writing the code BaseTableQueryCreator ct = new MetaTableQueryCreator(<primarykeyhere>); I may need to access the subclass' properties via BaseTableQuerycreator

Comment: I don't really see what is the MEF part of the problem here, but I think that the comment by @slugster is in the good track. Did you know that you can export and import referencing interfaces? Maybe you want all your derived classes to implement some interface (which can be empty, just to use it as a tag) and then import them wherever you like, and cast them to whatever you need. They can even implement several interfaces and be exported many times.

Comment: your problem is ill-defined.